# Swift: Ambiguous reference to member '+' when using .sorted on optional

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, option-type

I am trying to use .sorted on an array whose properties are optional, and I get this error:

> Ambiguous reference to member '+'

I'm not sure how to deal with the optional here, and adding ! to force unwrap doesn't work (I am certain the array will have a value by the time this code runs).

```
let sortedoptions = decisions[selectedDecision].options.sorted(by: { $0.ratings.reduce(0, +) < $1.ratings.reduce(0, +) } )
```

And the Options class:

```
struct Option: Codable {
    var title: String
    var ratings: [Int?]
}
```

Would anyone know how to fix this please?

Comment: Why are ratings optional? Is there a deference between having a `nil` rating, and just not having it at all?

Comment: Hey @Alexander, yes, I wanted to use that to fill any missing values with default ones on a later page. The user creates a list of Options and a list of Aspects, and then the aspects must be duplicated for every option, so Option1: Aspect1: 5, Aspect2: 8, Option2: Aspect1: 3, Aspect2: 10. The user can also go back and add more options or aspects, which would now have empty ratings, so I wanted the page where they edit the ratings to give them default values if they're nil.

Comment: I don't follow. What's an `Aspect` and what's it's connection to an `Option`?

Comment: This is an app that's supposed to help you visualise your decisions, so you would add the Options you're considering and the Aspects they affect then rate the way each Option would impact each Aspect. The model looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/92tl64rolntilyf/Screenshot%202019-08-10%20at%2016.37.42.png?dl=0 I managed to solve the problem in the end without a nil (I'm checking whether the array contains an index instead), but this is probably a pretty primitive solution, so if you'd be open to it, I could share the file with you and get your thoughts, there might be a much better way.

Comment: Yeah if you have a public Git repo for it, that'd be ideal.

Comment: The project isn't public, but I've uploaded the files related to decisions here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bf9lk0s0esh6nxj/files.zip?dl=0 and I could also share a TestFlight public link if you'd like to see how this works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197769/discussion-between-alexander-and-cristianmoisei).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by

`let sortedoptions = decisions[selectedDecision].options.sorted(by: { $0.ratings.reduce(0, {x,y in x + y!}) < $1.ratings.reduce(0, {x,y in x + y!})} )`

This is because as the error says addition cannot be performed on two `Int?` types.

Also this is assuming the array values will never be nil

Safer option would be to replace `y!` by `y ?? 0`